# Haystack queryset contains None elements

Tags: django-haystack

I'm using Haystack for search, and the resulting SearchQuerySet returned contains None elements:

```
>> SearchQuerySet().models(Question, Document, Idea)
>> [<SearchResult: idea.idea (pk=3875)>, None, None, None]
```

Running rebuild_index doesn't help. If I remove the .models() call from the first line, the problem goes away. I could just filter out None elements from the results, but I wanted to know if this is intended behaviour?

I am using Django 1.4, Whoosh, and Haystack 2.0.0-beta

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but [this guy](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/django-haystack/none/django-haystack/XSjIr8wx3lA/7f82x2QJ9cUJ) suggests using Solr instead of Whoosh.

Comment: Update : now I've tried it and it works with Solr.

Comment: everybody knows that elastic search or solr do and perform better - but for small to mid-sized sites, Whoosh is very ok IMHO and makes no trouble installing/setting up (only afterwards, haha).

Comment: @zimkies are you using solr as well, now?

Comment: @zimkies having an answer two years later, you could accept it after two more years, no? ;-) at least it is the only answer that does somehow resolve the problem, and does not suggest installing a different backend ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem when haystack index had records without corresponding records in DB.

Comment: Thanks, this isn't the problem though. It turns out the 'None' values correspond to User objects. Apparently the _models_ function removes hits that aren't of the right model type but leaves a None type instead of filtering them out

Comment: Can't you say, is this problem only for 'whoosh' backend? Does using Solr engine solves it?

Comment: So there's no solution for Whoosh then?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is definitly not the intended behaviour, and as I can see, seems to be related to a design decision in Whoosh. And, as of December 2015, this still seems to be an issue, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1171). Also, I can reproduce it with my setup (django 1.8.5, haystack 2.4.1, Whoosh 2.7.0) - that's why I came here.

Quick and dirty solution that worked for me: Define a new field on your index (type/model/tomato), set it the same for each model, and filter against that value:

`.filter(type='my_modelname')`

instead of

`.models(MyModel)`.

I don't know (yet) how this scales, but seems to work ok.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem using Whoosh, installed Elasticsearch and the `None` elements went away.